# Associating users and articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I just started with Rails and right now looking over HABTM. I am reading the DHH book and I see that he has two models namely article and user. They have HABTM relationships. I am wondering however whether I need to create a separate migration for the articles_users model by myself or will Rails do it for me?

If so, what happen if I create a new user and associate it with an article? Will Rails know right away what to enter inside the `articles_users` table?

Ex:

```
u = User.new(:name => "John");
a = Article.new(:title =>"Rails");
```

#can I do this?

```
a.user << u
```

#will rails automatically create an entry inside `articles_users` table?

I am somewhat confused on where Rails stop in terms of making tables for us or whatnot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to manually create the table with a migration.  However, most rails developers now prefer Has Many Through instead of HABTM.  Another benefit is that when you generate the "join model" rails will make a migration for you!

Comment: can you give me an example of the script/generate command for the join model you just mentioned?

Comment: try: script/generate model articles_users article_id:integer user_id:integer

Comment: Brian is correct.  Another advantage to using HMT is that you have an entire model that you can later add methods or more attributes for.